# Objective-C & iOS Dev

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I just started developing iOS using objective-c, and I've had some trouble getting used to the syntax. I'm finally beginning to understand the semantics- even the reason for them, but one thing is puzzling me.

When defining the outlets and actions for an iOS app: why are the outlets defined within the interface declaration, versus the actions and other declarations defined outside the interface declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because outlets have no implementation. They are just plain old instance variables.

Actions, on the other hand, are methods (object functions) and they need to be implemented.

---

Methods are declared actually, but outside the curly brackets, while ivars happen to be declared inside the curly brackets. Everything between @interface and @end is in the interface.

---

```
@interface MyClass {
   instance variables here. outlets are also instance variables
}

methods here. actions are also methods
@end
```

There is no reason **why**. This simply is the syntax. :)

Comment: Similar way of looking at it: outlets are just pointers to where your interface objects are going to be. Apple's dev tools try to adhere to a strict Model View Controller (MVC) design philosophy, which involves separating how your data is displayed, stored, and where the business logic resides.

Answer (score 0):

`IBOutlet` and `IBAction` are not data-types; they're just for Interface Builder to know which variables are outlets and which methods are actions.

So, when you write this:

```
@interface AClass
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *someButton;
}

- (IBAction) buttonTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

It actually ends up being something like this when compiled:

```
@interface AClass
{
   UIButton *someButton;
}

- (void) buttonTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You actually have the option of defining the outlets in a property declaration if you're more comfortable:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UITextField*    aTextField;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* aTextField;

@end
```

IBAction and IBOutlet are really just clues to interface builder, here are the actual definitions:

```
#ifndef IBOutlet
#define IBOutlet
#endif

#ifndef IBOutletCollection
#define IBOutletCollection(ClassName)
#endif

#ifndef IBAction
#define IBAction void
#endif
```

Comment: Note there is a subtle difference here between placing IBOutlet on the ivar versus on the property: putting it on the property will call the property's setter (which in this case will retain the object, meaning it must be released in `dealloc`), while placing it on the ivar will just assign the ivar without calling the setter method.

Comment: DONT DO THAT! The property aTextField automatically has an instance variable named _aTextField. You just declared a second instance variable named aTextField. self.aTextField accesses _aTextField, while self->aTextField or just aTextField in an instance method accesses aTextField. This is more than one bug just waiting to bite you.